# AngularJS: Making multiple <div>text fields</div> editable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have multiple divs like this:

```
<div>{{form.name}}</div>
```

I can manually make them editable like so:

```
<div ng-hide="editorEnabled">
    {{form.name}}
    <button ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled">Edit</button>
</div>
<div ng-show="editorEnabled">
      <input ng-model="form.name">
      <button ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled">Done</button>
</div>
```

Is it possible to automate this somehow, so that I don't have to copy/paste code?  I thought about using ng-repeat, but my model is not just an array--it is a json object, and not all field should have this applied to them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can add a class to the entire form. When class "edit-mode" is present, you can hide the divs with the text, and show the divs with the inputs. When it is removed, you could hide the divs with inputs and show the divs with texts. This would be the easiest, I think.

[HERE IS AN EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2zjBDh0k2dbC9LHYHFX?p=preview) if you need one.

Add a special class to the bits that need this applied, and then use the CSS to hide/show their editable stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime candidate for a custom directive. I found a few examples of a "click-to-edit" directive when I searched a while ago. You can also write your own for the experience (as I did).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good fit for creating a directive. I created a similar directive that allowed in place edit. See here http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/6gMXL/

Here is the relevant code

```
app.directive('editable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=model',
            defaultValue: '@defaultval',
            removeFn: '=onDelete'
        },
        templateUrl:'editable-template',
        controller: function($scope) {},
        // The linking function will add behavior to the template
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.editorEnabled = false;

            scope.unEdit = function($event) {
                scope.model = angular.copy(scope.editModel);
                scope.editorEnabled = false;
                if ($event != null) $event.preventDefault();
            };

            scope.enableEditor = function() {
                scope.editModel = angular.copy(scope.model);
                scope.editorEnabled = true;
                // The element enable needs focus and we wait for milliseconds before allowing focus on it.
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    element.find('input').focus().select();
                }, 100);
            };
        }
    }
});
```